# how can i add uiview to the cellForRowAtIndexPath？

Tags: ios, uitableview, view, uiview

I created mycell，and in myTableview I created a

```
@property (strong ,nonatomic)NSArray *contentPictureArray;
```

this is：

```
self.contentPictureArray = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"wallha@2x.png"],@"wallha@2x.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"wallha@2x.png"]];
```

I want to use `cell.contentPictureView.view=[self.contentPictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];` but not true ，how can I add mycell to the cellForRowAtIndexPath？

```
cell.stateView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(XB, HeiB+NY, WidB, 0)];
    [cell addSubview:cell.stateView];

    cell.contentTextView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WidB, 0)];
    [cell.stateView addSubview:cell.contentTextView];//动态文字部分

    cell.contentLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, WidB, 0)];
    [cell.contentTextView addSubview:cell.contentLabel];//动态文字label

    cell.allContentBtn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.contentLabel.frame.size.height, HeiB, 2*NX)];
    [cell.contentTextView addSubview:cell.allContentBtn];//全文显示按钮

    cell.contentPictureView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, cell.stateView.frame.origin.y+2*NX, HeiB+NY, 0)];
    [cell.stateView addSubview:cell.contentPictureView];

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    KBTableViewCell*cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[KBTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdent:@"cell"];
    }

    if(indexPath.row==0||indexPath.row==1){

        cell.iconImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"];

    }

    cell.contentLabel.text=[self.listArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = [self.nameArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.timeLabel.text  =[self.timeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.contentPictureView.=[self.contentPictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand. 
In your code: 
[self.contentPictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]   is UIImage

cell.contentPictureView.view is UIView ?

so you code:

```
cell.contentPictureView.view = [self.contentPictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]
```

how you can do it?

Comment: yes ，I am writing，but not true，there is red error：“Expected identefier，how can i do

Answer (score 0):

Add the image like this in your cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10,100, 200)];
imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imageView.image = [contentPictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ;
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: i use your method Add the image like this in my cellForRowAtIndexPath，the project crashed，it looks say UIImage * img is nil

Comment: Do you have the images added in your project resources?

Comment: how can i contact with you

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize array with image name only like below.

```
self.contentPictureArray = @[@"wallha@2x","wallha@2x",@"wallha@2x"]];
```

Now use below code:

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10,100, 100)];
imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[contentPictureArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] ofType:@"png"]] ;
[cell.contentView addSubview:imageView];
```

Also if you want you can create a custom cell also.